# PHP : Preg_match not work when have "/"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

This one is killing me:

```
echo preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/",'downcom');
```

This one print 0 , because it wrong.

```
echo preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/",'down.com');
```

This one print 1 , its right.

My question is: why this one still print 1.

```
echo preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/",'down.c/om');
```

I want my preg_match check domain , domain.com only. I don't want people enter domain.com/asda , but it still allow people enter / even I don't set / in [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add the beginning and end boundaries `^`, `$`:

```
echo preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/",'down.c/om');
//---------------^^^--------------------------------^^^
// Prints 0
```

The reason yours failed was that the pattern did in fact match the string `down.c`, but since you didn't include the `$` end of string, any additional characters did not need to match the regex pattern so `/om` could be ignored.  By including `$`, you force the test string to be matched up to its end.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your regular expression to see what it's doing:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)
```

This first part is saying **1 or more of these characters**, which matches "down" just fine.

```
\.
```

Then we match a single dot.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Then we match **1 or more** of these characters. The 'c' fulfilled the *1 or more* rule, so it returns true. If you want to match exactly three characters, change your regular expression to something like:

```
echo preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})/",'down.c/om');
```

That should return false, as you expect. Michael's positional anchor tip (from his answer) is also useful, though you'll want to make sure what comes in has been trimmed ($ can match against \n, as I found out yesterday). You could also use the `D` modifier or the `\z` assertion to make sure you're at the end of the line. Here's how it might look when put together:

```
echo preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})$/D",'down.c/om');
```